# VMWare Workstation: Use Windows Virtual Desktops to quickly switch between host an VM

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware, vmware-workstation

I am using VMWare Workstation 15 to virtualize a linux VM on my Windows 10 host. In Windows 10, you can have multiple (virtual) desktops and switch between them using a hotkey <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>Left arrow</kbd>/<kbd>Right arrow</kbd>.

What I now want to do is have Desktop 1 with my normal WIndows 10 OS, and have VMWare Workstation on the second virtual desktop in full-screen mode, so that I can switch between the two quickly.

Switching from the OS desktop to the VMWare desktop obviously works, the other way around however not. I suspect that the key combination is catched by the VM. Is there any workaround for that?

Comment: `Is there any workaround for that?` - You can change the modifier key to something other than CTRL since the shortcut to switch Virtual desktops cannot be changed.  I can convert this into an answer if it's an acceptable workaround.

Comment: Hi @Ramhound, what exactly do you mean by changing the modifier key? I was under the impression that the CTRL+Windows combination is sent to the guest but should be handled by the Windows host instead

Comment: It's not quite what you're asking for, but you might want to try using [`vmware-kvm`](https://blogs.vmware.com/workstation/2014/03/whats-cool-vmware-kvm-utility.html) which is included with VMware Workstation which allows cycling among the host desktop and VMs.

Comment: Hi jamesdin, thanks. Actually I gave up the virtualization approach as Ubuntu was showing very strange behavior in Workstation (like random freezes, sound not working, ...), I just installed it on the disk now and use it natively. Should I delete the question or should I leave it open for further answers?

Comment: I'm looking for a similar solution but so far no luck!